# Why does String.valueOf(null) throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, overloading, api-design

according to the documentation, the method [`String.valueOf(Object obj)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) returns:

> if the argument is `null`, then a string equal to `"null"`; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.

But how come when I try do this:

```
System.out.println("String.valueOf(null) = " + String.valueOf(null));
```

it throws NPE instead? (try it yourself if you don't believe!)

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
```

How come this is happening? Is the documentation lying to me? Is this a major bug in Java?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

The issue is that `String.valueOf` method is *overloaded*:

- [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [`String.valueOf(char[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%5B%5D%29)

Java Specification Language mandates that in these kind of cases, *the most specific overload* is chosen:

#### [JLS 15.12.2.5  Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the *most specific* method is chosen.

A `char[]` *is-an* `Object`, but not all `Object` *is-a* `char[]`. Therefore, `char[]` is *more specific* than `Object`, and as specified by the Java language, the `String.valueOf(char[])` overload is chosen in this case.

`String.valueOf(char[])` expects the array to be non-`null`, and since `null` is given in this case, it then throws `NullPointerException`.

The easy "fix" is to cast the `null` explicitly to `Object` as follows:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf((Object) null));
// prints "null"
```

#### Related questions

- [How does polymorph ambiguity distinction work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659496/how-does-polymorph-ambiguity-distinction-work/)
- [Which overload will get selected for null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545501/which-overload-will-get-selected-for-null-in-java)

---

#### Moral of the story

There are several important ones:

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 41: Use overloading judiciously*

  - Just because you can overload, doesn't mean you should every time
  - They can cause confusion (especially if the methods do wildly different things)
- Using good IDE, you can check which overload is selected at compile time

  - With Eclipse, you can mouse-hover on the above expression and see that *indeed*, the `valueOf(char[])` overload is selected!
- Sometimes you want to explicitly cast `null` (examples to follow)

#### See also

- [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading)
- [Method Overloading. Can you overuse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248222/method-overloading-can-you-overuse-it)

---

#### On casting `null`

There are at least two situations where explicitly casting `null` to a specific reference type is necessary:

- To select overloading (as given in above example)
- To give `null` as a single argument to a vararg parameter

A simple example of the latter is the following:

```
static void vararg(Object... os) {
    System.out.println(os.length);
}
```

Then, we can have the following:

```
vararg(null, null, null); // prints "3"
vararg(null, null);       // prints "2"
vararg(null);             // throws NullPointerException!

vararg((Object) null);    // prints "1"
```

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) - to understand how it's implemented

#### Related questions

- [Why null cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315846/why-null-cast)
- [Difference between double… and double[] in formal parameter type declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888305/difference-between-double-and-double-in-formal-parameter-type-declaration/)

Comment: Another suggestion: When you overload a method and one argument could be called on two overloads (such as `null` in this case), make sure that both overloads act the same with regard to that value!

Comment: @Joachim: I just read the item, and was pleasantly surprised to find that these two methods were explicitly discussed! Bloch went a step further and claim that since `String.valueOf(Object)` and `valueOf(char[])` do completely different things anyway (irrespective of `null` or not) that perhaps they shouldn't have been overloads in the first place.

Comment: Got a question... if you have a method that returns an Object then the statement `return null;` would be the exact same thing as `return (Object) null;`?

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that you're calling [`String.valueOf(char[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char[])) and **not** [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)).

The reason for this is that Java will always choose the most specific version of an overloaded method that works with the provided parameters. `null` is a valid value for an `Object` parameter, but it's also a valid value for a `char[]` parameter.

To make Java use the `Object` version, either pass in `null` via a variable or specify an explicit cast to Object:

```
Object o = null;
System.out.println("String.valueOf(null) = " + String.valueOf(o));
// or
System.out.println("String.valueOf(null) = " + String.valueOf((Object) null));
```

Answer (score 5):

A bug, numbered [4867608](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4867608) was filed for this way back in 2003, which was resolved as "won't fix" with this explanation.

> We can't change this due to compatibility constraints. Note that it is
> the public static String valueOf(char data[]) method which ends up
> being invoked and it does not mention the replacement of "null" for
> null arguments.
>
> #### @###.### 2003-05-23

Answer (score -1):

Use `String.valueOf(null: Any)` in Scala, otherwise `String.valueOf(null: Array[Char])` is inferred. Likewise in java you need an explicit cast if you're not happy with the implicit cast. In IntelliJ, Ctrl+B on your use of valueOf will get you to the version of valueOf you use among the many you can use.