# debug attribute can have values as "on" in JAVAC tag of ant script

Tags: java, debugging, ant

I am a little confused. Can someone please help with the below doubt

I am writing an ant script which will compile a java code and deploy the files. Please note that in the javac tag i have added an attribute **debug="on"**. As per the docs leagle values for debug are **true or false** (not **on and off**).

As far as i know, debug will links Java code back to the line number, the variable name in the source, and the name of the source itself (using debuglevel attribute).

Out of curiocity i added debug="on" and thought that i will receive "Unknown source" in the stack trade instead of line number but instead i am receiving correct stack trace with line number.

Questin: is my understanding of debug attribut uncorrect. If yes, can you please help me with it?

Pasted below is the edited stack trade. i am getting the same for both debug=true and debug=on.

```
> javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server
> localhost:1099 [Root exception is
> javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server
> localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException:
> Connection refused: connect]]     at
> org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:216)    at
> org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1116)    at
> org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:478)   at
> org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:471)   at
> javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)   at
> com.XXXXX.products.fi.mbs.server.someclass2.<init>(someclass2.java:85)
>   at
> com.XXXXX.products.eurorepo.server.someclass1.<init>(someclass1.java:21)
>   at
> com.XXXXX.products.eurorepo.server.boot.someclass3.registerFactories(someclass3.java:136)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
> com.XXXXX.products.common.someclass4.callMethod(someclass4.java:154)
>   at
> com.XXXXX.products.server.someclass5.callMethod(someclass5.java:118)
>   at
> com.XXXXX.products.common.someclass4.callMethod(someclass4.java:141)
>   at
> com.XXXXX.products.server.someclass5.registerFactories(someclass5.java:48)
>   at com.XXXXX.cs.yyy.yyyServer.init(yyyServer.java:292)  at
> com.XXXXX.cs.yyy.yyyServer.<init>(yyyServer.java:135)     at
> com.XXXXX.cs.yyy.yyyServer.bootyyyServer(yyyServer.java:494)  at
> com.XXXXX.cs.yyy.yyyServer.main(yyyServer.java:691)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
> Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect
> to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException:
> Connection refused: connect]  at
> org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:191)
>   ... 24 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
> connect   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
> java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)  at
> java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
>   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)   at
> java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)    at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)  at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)  at
> java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)   at
> java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:276)   at
> org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:69)
>   at
> org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:62)
>   at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:187)
```

Comment: Just a comment: i just wanted to check if On/OFF is interchangeable with true/False in case of debug attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks to a post in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216749/unknown-source-in-java-stack-trace-yet-line-numbers-are-in-the-class-file) and [this](http://issueblogit.com/java-exception-line-number-is-unknown-source/) i figured out the answer. Yes, ON/OFF can be interchanged with true/false.