# build.properties addition: compilerArg in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to add the following compiler attributes to an Eclipse plugin I developed for Lotus Notes, so that when an exception occurs, I get the line where it occurred:

```
debug=true debuglevel=lines,vars,source
```

I've thought this is the best way to do this, after seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216749/unknown-source-in-java-stack-trace-yet-line-numbers-are-in-the-class-file?lq=1)

So I've put in the build.properties file this new line

```
compilerArg ="-debug=true -debuglevel=lines,vars,source "
```

It doesn't show the lines where exceptions occur (still shows "Unknown Source")

Any thoughts are appreciated.

EDIT: I am using Eclipse to run the build, from the update site project.

Comment: Which tool do you use to build your plug-in?

Comment: Edited, using Eclipse usual Build command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, it seems Lotus Notes hides line numbers by default, despite them being present in the classes:

http://lekkimworld.com/2010/04/14/java_class_line_numbers_for_plugin_developers.html

> Line numbers are removed from the classes added to the shared class
>   cache to reduce the memory needed for the memory mapped classes. To
>   re-enable the line numbers, one needs to edit the
>   \framework\rcp\deploy\jvm.properties file and add comment out
>   the ignorelinenumbers vm argument.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses the Eclipse 'ecj' compiler not 'javac' so you need to specify arguments that 'ecj' understands (see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm)). So `-g` or `-g:lines,vars,source` sets all debug information.

Comment: I've had no luck compiling and building like that, surely I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You need to tell us which tools you are using to do the build. Lines numbers are normally on by default.

Comment: these args are for an offline pde-build and belong inside build.properties of the build. They will not work inside the plugins build.properties.

Comment: @greg-449 I am using Eclipse's Build command. I was expecting that they would be taken into consideration in that case. Check edited question. Thanks again

Comment: @PeterKirschner where do I find the appropriate build.properties file to place these arguments in?

Comment: Thanks again, guys! It seems it was the environment's fault, deliberately not showing line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The template for a headless pde build is found inside each eclipse-sdk at

```
<eclipse-sdk>\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_<version>\templates\headless-build\build.properties
```

If you follow the description for an [PDE product build](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_product_build.htm?cp=4_2_0_0) you should use the template from above inside `<buildConfigurations>/build.properties`. Similar thing is described here for [PDE feature builds](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_feature_build.htm?cp=4_2_0_1).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems though the environment I was publishing the plugin in was deliberately hiding the lines, for performance improvement