# Unknow source in exception stacktrace

Tags: java, exception

In exception stackTrace I am receiving Unknown Source, instead of line number of source code.

Build was created using Ant, *OS RedHat Linux and deployed on Application Server as Weblogic.*

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at util.NotificationUtil.sendLimitChangeNotifications(Unknown Source)
            at bc_hierarchy.mailer.BCPositionNotificationMailer.process(Unknown Source)
            at service.message.FRMessenger.invokeTargetClass(Unknown Source)
            at service.message.FRMessenger.processMessage(Unknown Source)
            at service.message.FRQueueMsgListener.onMessage(Unknown Source)
```

What are the way to fix line number issue so I can resolve my Exception? (Because of security reason I can provide source code here)

Is there any way So I do not need to recompile?

Comment: You need to keep the line numbers when compiling. "I feel lucky" on that search engine gave this random link: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1122360

Answer (score 3):

The class files does not have line number(debug) information.  You cannot accurately get it without debug version jars/class.

Note that by default some build tools produce classes with debug=off. For example see [ant javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Comment: @ Makoto : added information ant-javac debug  flag.

Answer (score 1):

See: [(Unknown Source) in Exception stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132302/unknown-source-in-exception-stack-trace)

"This is normally related to missing debug information."

You need to get a copy of the original source code and add it to your project...or decompile it.