# Javadoc error - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: javadoc, invocationtargetexception

I am trying to generate the uml diagram from yDoc library. It basically uses Javadoc to parse tha Java source files. However, when I am trying to execute the command from terminal(OS X), I am getting following error:

```
javadoc: error - In doclet class ydoc.doclets.YStandard,  method start has thrown  
an exception  
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.taglets.TagletManager.  
getConstructorCustomTags()[Lcom/sun/tools/doclets/internal/toolkit/taglets/Taglet;


at ydoc.doclets.F$_A.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ydoc.doclets.F.B(Unknown Source)
at ydoc.doclets.F.E(Unknown Source)
at ydoc.doclets.J.setSpecificDocletOptions(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.setOptions(Configuration.java:560)
at ydoc.doclets.J.setOptions(Unknown Source)
at ydoc.doclets.C.A(Unknown Source)
at ydoc.doclets.YStandard.start(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:310)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:189)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:366)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:219)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:205)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:64)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

I ran the following execution command:

```
javadoc @doc/examples/options.sample.linux <Java file path>
```

I am also getting same error when trying from Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I am getting the exact same error trace following their instructions for running it in eclipse. I am also on OS X.
https://www.yworks.com/products/yDoc/doc/usersguide.html

Comment: I also tried instructions at https://power2build.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/uml-doclet-in-eclipse/ adding JRE source compatibility 1.5 and other VM options

Answer (score 0):

@codeblues and @Grant M, I just noticed this question. I am the author of that [blog post](http://power2build.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/uml-doclet-in-eclipse) Grant M mentioned. I just tried my instructions again, I am getting Javadoc with UML diagram as expected.

To me, this sounds like a version mismatch between JDK (and JavaDoc)and Ydoc.jar. Javadoc related classes are in a jar called tools.jar in jdk\lib folder. You may want to check your classpath to see if it includes the right JDK. You can probably try which javadoc on *nix (or "where javadoc" on Win 7+ to find out the JDK location used).

The mention "Unknown source' in your exception seems to indicate you are pointing to JRE instead of JDK?? Also, see this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132302/unknown-source-in-exception-stack-trace) about "(unknown source)" in Java Exceptions.

I hope you can get this to work, to see the UMLs jump into your Javadoc!

HTH

Sam

Comment: OK, I just tried changing a few settings - when I changed the Javadoc command to be from Java 1.8 (C:\Java\jre1,8.0_65\bin\javadoc.exe), with all else same, I was able to get this error.  I did try  JDK 1.6 and 1.7, they worked fine.  And I just noticed on yworks page, https://www.yworks.com/en/products_ydoc.html; they only mention upto 1.7.   So, I am guessing mixing Java 1.8 with ydoc is your issue.