# Getting stuck in Java processBuilder.start()

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, processbuilder

I'm doing a small Java project which is making a simple Java IDE with using `Processbuilder` class.

The IDE get input the Java file name (ex: `test.java`) and only compiles the Java file where exists in the same project folder.

But I'm getting difficulty in error messages about `processBuilder.start()`.

Can anyone see my code and what is wrong with my code?

I can't handle with error messages and fix my codes.

Here is error messages when I clicked compile button:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at sample$2.mouseClicked(sample.java:138)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) .. etc
```

And my some codes here:

```
 static String file_Name;
 static String JAVA_FILE_LOCATION;
 static String[] command = {"javac", JAVA_FILE_LOCATION};
```

Also, I get input and initialize above `String` variables before `btn_Compile` event occured.

(EX: `file_Name = "test.java"`,
`JAVA_FILE_LOCATION = "javaProjectFolder\project\test.java"`)

```
 void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    btn_Compile.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { // JButton btn_Compile
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                Process process = processBuilder.start();
                int idx = file_Name.lastIndexOf(".");
                String _fileName = file_Name.substring(0, idx); //
                process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"java", "-cp", "bin", _fileName}).start();

                if (process.getErrorStream().read() != -1) {
                    inputStream = process.getErrorStream();
                }
                else { // compile succeed
                    System.out.println("compiled successfully ...");
                    inputStream = process.getInputStream();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
 }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    sample s = new sample();
    s.test();
}
```

Comment: Do you actually initialise `file_Name` and `JAVA_FILE_LOCATION`? I get no exception. Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132302/unknown-source-in-exception-stack-trace).

Comment: Have you already debugged your code and checked the content of `command` at line 138? Or what if you insert `System.out.println(command)` after `try {`?

Comment: `JAVA_FILE_LOCATION` is not initialized, so it is null.  This means your next line of code is actually doing this: `static String[] command = {"javac", null};`  Changing JAVA_FILE_LOCATION later does nothing to alter the elements of the `command` array.  You must reassign `command[1]`.

Comment: Also consider [`javax.tools.JavaCompiler`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20javax.tools.JavaCompiler).

Comment: You could make use `JavaCompiler` instead [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes/21544850#21544850)

Comment: Why are you making two `ProcessBuilder`s?  You're also not waiting for the execution of the first `ProcessBuilder` to finish before executing the second, which means the first could still be running

Comment: Thanks to all of you. the  command was problem. I fix it. I really appreciate.