# When does the "~[classes/:?]" string (or similar such as ~[?:?]) appear at the end of stack-trace lines in Java?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application that is developed by Java 8.0 and deployed on Tomcat 8.0. In some scenarios, I've got an error with a string with which I'm not familiar. For example, I have an error same as below in one of my scenarios:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6555.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:649) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4745) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1152) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1011) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8215.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    ... 64 more
```

I've reinstalled Java and Tomcat, but I've been still getting this error.
Does anyone have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at your logging configs ...

Comment: YOu are probably using a [JRE instead of a JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3132349/2834978).

Comment: @StephenC This string appears in some stack-traces, not in all of that. Although I checked logging configs and there isn't special setting.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz No, I'm using JDK.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz -  This is nothing to do with JRE vs JDK.   The Q you linked to is about *missing* source / debug information not *extra* packaging information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normal behavior for off-the-shelf Java.  So we must conclude that these stacktraces are not being generated by your code calling `Throwable::printStacktrace()`

After doing a bit of digging, one possible cause is that you are using Logback for your logging, and in particular using `%xThrowable` rather `%throwable` in a `PatternLayout` pattern.  This includes extra packing information in the stacktrace with the syntax that you are seeing.  You should refer to the [Logback documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) for more details, because there are many variations possible in the pattern language.

The documentation also says:

> Please note that given its potential cost, computation of packaging data is disabled by default. *When computation of packaging data is enabled, `PatternLayout` will automatically assume the `%xThrowable` suffix instead of `%throwable` suffix at the end of the pattern string*.

So the suffixes could be a side-effect of doing this:

```
 <configuration packagingData="true">
    ...
 </configuration>
```

in the Logback config.

---

**UPDATE**: You said that you are using Log4j2 rather than Logback.

Log4j2 has an equivalent pattern-based logging layout with `%xThrowable` support; see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

> Please consider that this string appears in some stack-traces, not in all of that.

That can be explained if your application or some 3rd-party libraries that you are using are calling `Throwable::printStacktrace` or similar *directly* in some circumstances, and generating the stacktraces via the logger in others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, we aren't using Logback for our logging and there isn't any dependency on Logback (also transitive dependency).

Comment: @StephanC - We are using Log4j-2.0

Comment: @StephanC - Please consider that this string appears in some stack-traces, not in all of that.