# How to use null in switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

```java
Integer i = ...
    
switch (i) {
    case null:
        doSomething0();
        break;    
}
```

In the code above I can't use null in the switch case statement. How can I do this differently? I can't use `default` because then I want to do something else.

Comment: before switch check for null condition
if(i==null) {//dosomething}

Comment: This would actually make the switch useful.  Other pattern matching languages work this way.

Comment: in Java 21 or later you must only add an additional `default` case and it will work

Answer (score 386, accepted):

This was not possible with a `switch` statement in Java until Java 18. You had to check for `null` before the `switch`. But now, with pattern matching, this is a thing of the past. Have a look at [JEP 420](https://openjdk.org/jeps/420):

> Pattern matching and null
>
> Traditionally, switch statements and expressions throw
> NullPointerException if the selector expression evaluates to null, so
> testing for null must be done outside of the switch:

```
static void testFooBar(String s) {
     if (s == null) {
         System.out.println("oops!");
         return;
     }
     switch (s) {
         case "Foo", "Bar" -> System.out.println("Great");
         default           -> System.out.println("Ok");
     }
 }
```

> This was reasonable when switch supported only a few reference types.
> However, if switch allows a selector expression of any type, and case
> labels can have type patterns, then the standalone null test feels
> like an arbitrary distinction, and invites needless boilerplate and
> opportunity for error. It would be better to integrate the null test
> into the switch:

```
static void testFooBar(String s) {
    switch (s) {
        case null         -> System.out.println("Oops");
        case "Foo", "Bar" -> System.out.println("Great");
        default           -> System.out.println("Ok");   
  }
}
```

More about `switch` (including an example with a `null` variable) in [Oracle Docs - Switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: You can also use enums in switch statements.

Comment: It makes sense that you can't use a null Integer or other Wrapper class, because of unboxing. But what about enums and strings? Why can't they be null?

Comment: I'm not understanding why a short circuit of null being mapped to the "default" case or a special case for a null switch was not implemented for Strings.  It makes using switches to simplify code pointless since you always have to do a null check.  I'm not saying simplification is the only use for switches though.

Comment: @Reimius you don't always have to do a null check. If you respect the code contracts that you give to your methods, you can almost always manage to *not* have your code cluttered with null checks. Using asserts is always nice, though.

Comment: Answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/19931550/17428 contains a JLS quote. It basically says "The prohibition against using null as a switch label prevents one from writing code that can never be executed."

Comment: [This might change soon.](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/amber-spec-experts/2020-January/001910.html)

Comment: @Reimius if your null and default case matches, you can write it like this:
case null, default -> System.out.println("Value is missing");

Answer (score 148):

```
switch ((i != null) ? i : DEFAULT_VALUE) {
        //...
}
```

Comment: cleaner way than using one extra if else

Comment: For Groovy, you can use `switch (i ?: DEFAULT_VALUE)`

Answer (score 49):

`switch(i)` will throw a NullPointerException if `i` is `null`, because it will try to unbox the `Integer` into an `int`. So `case null`, which happens to be illegal, would never have been reached anyway.

You need to check that `i` is not null before the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 26):

Java docs clearly stated that:

The prohibition against using null as a switch label prevents one from writing code that can never be executed. If the switch expression is of a reference type, such as a boxed primitive type or an enum, a run-time error will occur if the expression evaluates to null at run-time.

You must have to verify for null before Swithch statement execution.

```
if (i == null)
```

See [The Switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

```
case null: // will never be executed, therefore disallowed.
```

Comment: The javadocs at your link no longer say "The prohibition against using null as a switch label [etc.]".

Comment: [This might change soon.](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/amber-spec-experts/2020-January/001910.html)

Answer (score 15):

Given:

```
public enum PersonType {
    COOL_GUY(1),
    JERK(2);

    private final int typeId;
    private PersonType(int typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public final int getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    public static PersonType findByTypeId(int typeId) {
        for (PersonType type : values()) {
            if (type.typeId == typeId) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

For me, this typically aligns with a look-up table in a database (for rarely-updated tables only).

However, when I try to use `findByTypeId` in a switch statement (from, most likely, user input)...

```
int userInput = 3;
PersonType personType = PersonType.findByTypeId(userInput);
switch(personType) {
case COOL_GUY:
    // Do things only a cool guy would do.
    break;
case JERK:
    // Push back. Don't enable him.
    break;
default:
    // I don't know or care what to do with this mess.
}
```

...as others have stated, this results in an NPE @ `switch(personType) {`. One work-around (i.e., "solution") I started implementing was to add an `UNKNOWN(-1)` type.

```
public enum PersonType {
    UNKNOWN(-1),
    COOL_GUY(1),
    JERK(2);
    ...
    public static PersonType findByTypeId(int id) {
        ...
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Now, you don't have to do null-checking where it counts and you can choose to, or not to, handle `UNKNOWN` types. (NOTE: `-1` is an unlikely identifier in a business scenario, but obviously choose something that makes sense for your use-case).

Comment: `UNKNOWN` is the best solution on this I've ever seen and overcomse nullchecks.

Answer (score 11):

## Pattern matching with `switch`

The null-behavior of switch statements has changed with the addition of pattern matching, which arrived with JDK 21 (and has *preview* state in JDK 17-20)

> #### Switches and null
>
> Traditionally, switch statements and expressions throw
> `NullPointerException` if the selector expression evaluates to `null`, so
> testing for `null` must be done outside of the switch.
>
> [...]
>
> This was reasonable when switch supported only a few reference types.
> However, if switch allows a selector expression of any type, and case
> labels can have type patterns, then the standalone null test feels
> like an arbitrary distinction, and invites needless boilerplate and
> opportunity for error. It would be better to integrate the null test
> into the switch by allowing a new **null case label**.

See [*JEP 441: Pattern Matching for switch*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/441)

This means basically that you *can* simply write

```
// As of Java 21
static void testFooBarNew(String s) {
    switch (s) {
        case null         -> System.out.println("Oops");
        case "Foo", "Bar" -> System.out.println("Great");
        default           -> System.out.println("Ok");
    }
}
```

Be aware though that you have to use `case null` explicitly:

> To maintain backward compatibility with the current semantics of switch, the default label does not match a null selector.

Answer (score 5):

You have to make a

```
if (i == null) {
   doSomething0();
} else {
   switch (i) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some libraries attempt to offer alternatives to the builtin java `switch` statement. [Vavr](http://www.vavr.io) is one of them, they generalize it to pattern matching.

Here is an example from [their documentation](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_pattern_matching):

```
String s = Match(i).of(
    Case($(1), "one"),
    Case($(2), "two"),
    Case($(), "?")
);
```

You can use any predicate, but they offer many of them out of the box, and `$(null)` is perfectly legal. I find this a more elegant solution than the alternatives, but this requires java8 and a dependency on the vavr library...

Answer (score 4):

I just learned today that you dont have to put another layer of indentation/curly brackets just because of the if that is checking for null. You can do either of these:

```
if (i == null) {
    // ...
} else switch (i) {
    case 1:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        // ...
}
```

or

```
if (i != null) switch (i) {
    case 1:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This works because the switch is a block itself - you're effectively making a one-line if block here, and could just as easily have `if (i == null) return defaultValue; switch (i) { }`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `String.valueOf((Object) nullableString)` 
like

```
switch (String.valueOf((Object) nullableString)) {
case "someCase"
    //...
    break;
...
case "null": // or default:
    //...
        break;
}
```

> See interesting SO Q/A: [*Why does String.valueOf(null) throw a NullPointerException*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131865/why-does-string-valueofnull-throw-a-nullpointerexception?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#answer-3131884)

Answer (score 3):

Based on @tetsuo answer, with java 8 :

```
Integer i = ...

switch (Optional.ofNullable(i).orElse(DEFAULT_VALUE)) {
    case DEFAULT_VALUE:
        doDefault();
        break;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can use primitives (int, char, short, byte) and String (Strings in java 7 only) in switch. primitives can't be null.
Check `i` in separate condition before switch.

Comment: You can use enums too.

Comment: if the enum is null, you'll have the same problem. BTW, it's pretty strange that switch can't handle null, since it has a default clause

Comment: @LeonardoKenji Default clause doesn't really have anything to do with null; whatever you're switching on it'll be dereferenced in order to check any other cases, so the default clause won't handle the null case (a NullPointerException is thrown before it has a chance to).

Comment: I think he meant the default clause should handle null as any other possible enum value that was not caught by the previous case's

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (String.valueOf(value)){
    case "null":
    default: 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just consider how the SWITCH might work,

- in case of primitives we know it can fail with NPE for auto-boxing
- but for **String** or **enum**, it might be invoking equals method, which obviously needs a LHS value on which equals is being invoked.
  So, given no method can be invoked on a null, *switch* cant handle null.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is one of possible solution:

```java
Integer i = Optional.ofNullable(...).orElse(VALUE);
```

`VALUE` is your special value that can be in your switch statement.