# Why java switch statement can't handle null, since it has a "default" clause?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Why java switch statement can't handle null, since it has a "default" clause?

For example, if you have something like

```
   switch(value){
     case VAL1: do_something1(); break;
     case VAL2: do_something2(); break;
     default: do_something3(); 
   }
```

shouldn't "default" deal with any other value, such as null?

Comment: as of 1.7(i think) it handles strings, but it only ever used to handle enums/ints, so maybe there's some legacy in there which won't allow nulls still. I'm sure somebody will know why

Comment: In fact it would be interesting to know the real reasons (the one we all see in the JLS is really dubious).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As always, [it's in the JLS:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

> ### 14.11. The `switch` Statement
>
> **All of the following must be true, or a compile-time error occurs:**
>
> - ...
> - No switch label is `null`.
>
> ...
> *The prohibition against using `null` as a switch label prevents one from writing code that can never be executed. If the switch expression is of a reference type, that is, `String` or a boxed primitive type or an enum type, then a run-time error will occur if the expression evaluates to `null` at run time. In the judgment of the designers of the Java programming language, this is a better outcome than silently skipping the entire `switch` statement or choosing to execute the statements (if any) after the `default` label (if any).*

Comment: Does this really answer the "why" ?

Comment: Edited to add the section which explains the reasoning.

Comment: That's better (apart the fact the *"no switch label is null"* isn't related). But that's looks like a *a posteriori* reasoning. It would have been more honest to say that it was easier to implement.

Answer (score 12):

In short, this design choice is in the *spirit of Java*.

The decision to throw an NPE when a switch expression evaluates to `null` is along the lines of other decisions made in Java, which always prefer throwing an exception to silently handling the `null` in the "obvious" way. The general rule seems to be that, when in doubt, the Java designers choose the option without default behavior. This has the side-effect of requiring boilerplate code at every use site.

Some would call this frustrating and unfortunate, but others disagree, maintaining that this is a safer decision.

For another potentially frustrating example see the *enchanced for* loop, which also throws an NPE if the collection is `null`, instead of acting as if the collection was empty. There are many more examples in the JDK library, where the caller must check all edge cases just to be allowed to treat them uniformly with the "normal" cases.

As a third notorious example, Java's checked exceptions require a lot of boilerplate to handle at every level of call stack depth, and lure less experienced programmers into several antipatterns. The results are often swallowed exceptions, the same exception being reported several times in the log, exceptions getting non-uniform handling at the wrong level of abstraction, etc.

Comment: I don't think the argument for NPEs is really "safer" but to facilitate a fail fast mentality, which makes errors many times easier to debug than swallowing errors. You could also argue, that you should strive to not expect null in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `SWITCH` on strings and other data types that can be `null`. This behaviour has been changed in Java 7 to allow string-switches.

See this question for more info:

[Why can't I switch on a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This is by definition. I wouldn't lose too much time on this as it's in the specifications.

On the other hand I find this quite practical in fact, as in case of being null it doesn' have a primitive type associated, so we can't know how to handle it properly.