# Passing Null Integer as Parameter

Tags: java

I have a method that takes an Integer `baz` as an optional parameter via overloading like so ...

```
public static void myMethod(String fooBar, Integer baz) {

    switch(baz){} // baz gets unboxed, NPE if it was null

    if(baz != null) {
        // Do something
    }
    else {
        // Do something else
    }
}

public static void myMethod(String fooBar) {
    myMethod(fooBar, null);
}
```

However, it's giving me a warning about the `else` statement saying it's dead code.  But when the method is called without `baz`, `baz` should just default to `null` so this should not be dead code.  Any explanation as to what I'm doing wrong here?  How would `baz` always be non-null even though I set it to `null` in the overloaded method?

**EDIT:**  Deleted actual code so my question is easier to read.

Comment: Is this the whole code? Or there are commented lines?

Comment: Who is the "it" that is warning you?

Comment: @molbdnilo Eclipse's compiler

Comment: @user2150250 NetBeans doesn't show warning... so it seems more of a preference of Eclipse.

Comment: @manouti There's code in place of the `Do somethings` but nothing that should affect this warning

Comment: This does not throw any warning/errors in Eclipse - you must have some other code that is setting the value of `baz` in the method to something other then null. Please post additional context.

Comment: Eclipse (Luna) doesn't show any warnings for this code. 
Did you disable the `Build automatically` option? If yes, did you rebuild the project after some changes?

Comment: One moment, it seems necessary for me to post the remainder of the code so I'll do so ...

Comment: Also, if you modify `baz` before `if`, e.g. `baz = 0;`, then Eclipse does show the warning.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Yeah if I default `baz` to `-1` instead of `null` and process it that way it doesn't give any warnings and works just fine but I wanted to know why I was getting the warning for default of `null`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant, the code snippet you've posted doesn't produce any warnings, but some statement in `// code here` could cause the warning. Please post your whole method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `switch` on the `Integer` variable. 
If the `Integer` is `null`, switch throws a `NullPointerException`, which you don't catch.

So it's not possible for the program flow to reach the `else` condition.

`Integer`s are *unboxed* if used in `switch` statement. You have to check for `null` explicitly, before the `switch` statement. See also [How to use null in switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332132/how-to-use-null-in-switch).

---

P.S. the minimal code to reproduce the problem is:

```
public static void myMethod(String fooBar, Integer baz) {

    switch(baz){} // baz gets unboxed, NPE if it was null

    if(baz != null) {
        // Do something
    }
    else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried changing the `switch` to a series of `if else`s, leaving the event of `tlsVersionMax` being `null` in the `else` rather than one of the `else if`s and that threw a null pointer exception when I ran my code.  Then I tried framing it in an `if(tlsVersionMax != null)` like is suggested in the link you posted and it worked.  Why can't the event of the variable being null just be covered by the `else`?

Comment: @user2150250, comparing an `Integer` with an `int` throws an NPE in Java if the `Integer` reference is `null`. This is because `Integer` is unboxed for value comparison operation. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3352791/2170192) covers it in all details.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that Eclipse tells you that your `else` statement is dead code is that you assign a new Integer to your `baz` before the `if` statement, therefore making it impossible to be `null`.

But since you're only showing a part of your code, that's hard to tell.

**EDIT**

The switch statement will throw a `NullPointerException` if `tlsVersionMax` is null. That's why you else statement is dead code.

Comment: It's _by far_ **not** the only way. Placing `if(baz == null) return;` in front of the existing `if` would also cause the warning.