# Java 17 null case with pattern matching

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement, pattern-matching, java-17

I have a Java 17 project using Eclipse 2022-03 and OpenJDK 17:

```
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I'm trying to use the new Java 17 switch features, so I tried this in a method:

```
return switch(testEnum) {
  case foo -> newFoo();
  case bar -> newBar();
}
```

That works fine. But then I tried this (because the value might be `null`):

```
return switch(testEnum) {
  case foo -> newFoo();
  case bar -> newBar();
  case null -> newDefault();
}
```

Eclipse underlines `null` in red and says:

> Pattern Matching in Switch is a preview feature and disabled by default. Use --enable-preview to enable

Compiling via Maven produces:

```
[ERROR] /project/src/main/java/com/example/FooBar.java:[432,38] null in switch cases is a preview feature and is disabled by default.
[ERROR]   (use --enable-preview to enable null in switch cases)
```

My Maven project has:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

I know the compiler release setting isn't being ignored; otherwise it would be defaulting to Java 8 (as per my parent POM) and not allowing pattern matching at all.

Isn't null cases with pattern matching part of Java 17? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `javac` say when you compile that file?

Comment: Good idea. I tried with Maven (which should be equivalent to `javac`), and it gave the same error! I updated the question with this additional information.

Comment: *"Isn't null cases with pattern matching part of Java 17? What am I doing wrong?"* - It is a preview feature, not a full feature.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232681 for how to enable preview features in Maven builds.

Comment: I had read https://medium.com/@javatechie/the-evolution-of-switch-statement-from-java-7-to-java-17-4b5eee8d29b7 , which seemed to indicate that the `null` cases was present in Java 17, but I guess that is different than pattern matching. So pattern matching is a full feature in Java 17, and `null` case statements is a full feature in Java 17, but pattern matching with `null` is only a preview feature in Java 17? That's sort of confusing.

Comment: In Java 17, _Pattern Matching for switch_ is a preview feature. See new features of Java 17: https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/17/

Comment: I just noted that enabling preview features under Eclipse isn’t helpful either. It compiles, but produces a `NullPointerException` at runtime. Seems, that support isn’t complete.

Answer (score 19):

**Update:** Pattern matching for `switch` [arrived in Java 21](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441).

## tl;dr

`switch` expressions != pattern matching with `switch`

You are mixing up the relatively new feature of *`switch` expressions* with the still-not-released feature of *pattern matching with `switch`*.

The `switch` feature in Java has been evolving through 3 phases, two completed:

- ☑️ `switch` statement (original feature in Java 1)
- ☑️ `switch` expression (Java 14+)
- ❌ Pattern matching for `switch`, including `case null` (previewed in Java 17, 18, 19, & 20)

## Do not conflate `switch` expressions with pattern matching

### Classic `switch`

Understand that historically, the Java `switch` statement has been hostile to `null` checks. See this Question, [*How to use null in switch*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10332132/642706). As shown there, code such as this:

```java
switch (i) {
    case null:
        doSomething0();
        break;    
}
```

… was not possible.

### `switch` expressions

Fast forward to Java 14, when `switch` expressions was added to Java. See [*JEP 361: Switch Expressions*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361). That allows the syntax seen in your first code example:

```java
return switch(testEnum) {
  case foo -> newFoo();
  case bar -> newBar();
}
```

But read the JEP. No mention of `null` — « crickets ».

### Pattern matching for `switch`

Fast forward further, to [*JEP 406: Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406). Note that this is a preview feature in Java 17, not a final, officially released feature. (To understand how preview features work, read [*JEP 12: Preview Features*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12).)

In that JEP 406, notice its second goal: ***Allow the historical null-hostility of switch to be relaxed when desired***.

Now search that page for “null” — 73 hits! That page explains the former policy of the Java language:

> Traditionally, `switch` statements and expressions throw `NullPointerException` if the selector expression evaluates to `null` …

Notice the mention of *statements*, the original `switch` syntax, and additionally *expressions*, the new syntax used in your code. In both cases, `null` check was forbidden.

That page goes on to explain the changes that motivate the inclusion of support for null checks. Read the JEP for will-written details.

The upshot is that you can use `case null` in a `switch` in Java 17 — but only if you go out of your way to **enable the preview feature**.

## Still in preview, in Java 20

- The preview in Java 17 was *not* finalized in Java 18.
- [Java 18 saw a second preview](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/420).
- A third preview appeared in Java 19: [*JEP 427: Pattern Matching for switch (Third Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/427).
- Currently in [4th preview in Java 20](https://openjdk.org/jeps/433), as of 2022-10.

[*"We will sell no wine before its time."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orson_Welles_Paul_Masson_advertisements#1978:_Original_ad%E2%80%94Beethoven,_Emerald_Dry)

There too, in Java 20, you will have to go out of your way to **activate the preview feature**.

And of course two reminders:

- Preview features should not be used in production for critical apps.
- Preview features are likely to change. That is their purpose, to gather feedback and suggestions leading to changes.

## Example

Let's try this code example. Notice how we use plain old syntax here, without the `->`. The arrow operator is not related to our discussion here.

```java
String x = null;
switch ( x )
{
    case "starburst":
        System.out.println( "Is starburst." );
        break;
    case null:
        System.out.println( "Whoops, null." );
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println( "Some other value found." );
        break;
}
```

In Java 17, by default, without enabling preview features we get this error while editing the code for `case null`:

> Patterns in switch are not supported at language level '17'
>
> Set language level to 17 (Preview) - Pattern matching for switch

After enabling preview features in Java 17, the code compiles without complaint. And it runs:

> Whoops, null.

Comment: Actually, `switch` expression do not have to use arrow labels. And a `switch` statement can now use arrow labels. Those two features are orthogonal - although I admit that they work very well together.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I added an example at the end showing the old-school syntax without arrow label. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This command line works for me:

```
$ javac -version
javac 17.0.3
$ javac  -source 17 -Xlint:preview --enable-preview org/kablambda/Main.java
org/kablambda/Main.java:10: warning: [preview] null in switch cases is a preview feature and may be removed in a future release.
            case null -> "c";
                 ^
1 warning
```