# Using a Switch-Case with an enum that has string values, in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, enums, switch-statement

In my application, I receive a response that has hard-coded values it can be.
I have created an enum with those responses as so:

```java
enum ResponseCode {
    APPROVED("AP"),
    REJECTED("RJ"),
    ...;

    private final String code;

    private ResponseCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

I would handle a response differently depending on which code I receive. I thought of using a switch-case to solve this problem.

```java
String response = functionThatReturnsString(); // Could be "AP" or "RJ" etc.

switch(response) {
case ResponseCode.APPROVED:
    // Response handling here
    break;
...
}
```

However, I get the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseCode to String`

Is there a way to get around this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I suggest you write a method in `ResponseCode` to convert a string code to the corresponding `ResponseCode`.

Comment: `ResponseCode rc= ResponseCode.valueOf(response);`, then switch on that value.

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: @AndyTurner I m confused as to why it is not a constant value. Isnt it already set inside the enum that the value of the response code is a certain final value APPROVED --> "AP"? Why is it not valid?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X the Java Language Specification has a narrow definition of constant expressions: things like literals are, things like method invocations are not. The compiler has no way of knowing that the method body only returns a constant-valued field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are switching on a `String`, but you are using `ResponseCode` as the cases, which doesn't make sense. A `String` can never match a `ResponseCode`.

There are multiple ways around this. Instead of an enum, you can use `static final` constants:

```
final class ResponseCode {
    private ResponseCode() {}
    public static final String APPROVED = "AP";
    public static final String REJECTED = "RJ";
}
```

```
switch (someResponseCode) {
    case ResponseCode.APPROVED -> { ... }
    case ResponseCode.REJECTED -> { ... }
    // remember to handle the case of not matching any response code!
    default -> { ... }
}
```

Alternatively, write a method that converts `String`s to your enum:

```
public static ResponseCode fromString(String s) {
    return switch (s) {
        case "AP" -> APPROVED;
        case "RJ" -> REJECTED;
        default -> null;
    };
    // or: Arrays.stream(ResponseCode.values()).filter(x -> x.code.equals(s)).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Note that you can remove the `code` field, if you don't need it for anything else.

Then you can `switch` like this:

```
switch (ResponseCode.fromString(someResponseCode)) {
    case APPROVED -> { ... }
    case REJECTED -> { ... }
    // remember to handle the case of not matching any response code!
    case null -> { ... }
}
```

Comment: Null isn't a supported case value, is it? (at least not for Java 11: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332132/how-to-use-null-in-switch)

Comment: @knittl Oh really? I was using Java 17 and it worked so I didn't think too much about it.

Comment: Oh, I see, those are switch expressions, not statements. Nevermind then

Answer (score 2):

Convert your String to a ResponseCode:

```
ResponseCode rc= ResponseCode.valueOf(response);
```

then switch on that value:

```
switch (rc) {
  case APPROVED:
    // Response handling here
    break;
...
}
```

You should probably also handle the case where the String can't be converted to an enum value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the enum directly:

```
ResponseCode responseCode = ...

switch(responseCode) {
case APPROVED:
    // Response handling here
    break;
...
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. OP is trying to switch on the String value using enum constants as cases.

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry don't get you. I do not qualify the enum

Comment: @AndyTurner OP is use the switch on a string I use it on the enum. But anyway it is unclear where the string comes from