# What is the difference between "(Object)null" and "null" in Java?

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception

Take a look at the following example:

```
class nul
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println (String.valueOf((Object)null));
    System.out.println (String.valueOf(null));
  }
}
```

The first `println` writes `null` but the second throws a `NullPointerException`.

Why is only the second line worth an exception? And what is the difference between the two `null`s? Is there a *real* `null` and a *fake* `null` in Java?

Comment: If you look at the Javadoc for String the answer is staring at you in the two relevant overloads of valueOf.

Comment: highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131865/why-does-string-valueofnull-throw-a-nullpointerexception?rq=1

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The first invocation will call the [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method, as you have explicitly typecasted `null` to `Object` reference. Conversely, the second one will invoke the overloaded [`String.valueOf(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%5B%5D%29) method, as `char[]` is more specific than `Object` for a `null` argument.

There are other overloaded versions of this method that accept primitive parameters, but those are not a valid match for a `null` argument.

From [JLS §15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> There may be more than one such method, in which case the most
>   specific one is chosen. The descriptor (signature plus return type) of
>   the most specific method is one used at run time to perform the method
>   dispatch.
>
> A method is applicable if it is either applicable by subtyping
>   (§15.12.2.2), applicable by method invocation conversion (§15.12.2.3),
>   or it is an applicable variable arity method (§15.12.2.4).
>
> [...]
>
> If several applicable methods have been identified during one of the
>   three phases of applicability testing, then the most specific one is
>   chosen, as specified in section §15.12.2.5.

Now check the source code of both the methods:

```
// This won't throw NPE for `obj == null`
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}

// This will throw `NPE` for `data == null`
public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
    return new String(data);
}
```

Comment: (Because the compiler resolves the methods called with `null` as a parameter as the most concrete as it can find. And `char[]` is more concrete than `Object`.)

Comment: So this is a Java bug, because the two implementations of `valueOf` do not do the same. The Object implementation thinks null should be printed as null, but the char array implementation thinks null should cause an exception. The same method thinks different about what is exceptional.

Comment: @ceving java bug? No, definitely not! The `Object` _should_ be printed as `null`. And a `null` `char[]` cannot be converted into a `String` so an exception is thrown. They are _different_ methods, that is the whole point. Where is the bug exactly?

Comment: Just a curiosity: when talking about methods, is it more standard to use the notation `Class#method(Type)` or `Class.method(Type)`? Is there a standard?

Comment: @htor `.` for `static` methods, and `#` for `instance` methods. Well, no there isn't any standard.

Comment: @BoristheSpider If they would have a different name, I would agree with you. But they have the same name and therefore are not different methods.

Comment: @ceving: they are two different overloads, so they simply aren't the same method. But I do see your point.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I'd still argue this violates the principle of least surprise, because intuitively upcasting a value shouldn't fix a failure. This intuition is justified by Liskov substitution principle (LSP).
If String.valueOf were a method of Object (which it can't in Java because Java isn't fully OO) and had this behavior, it would clearly violate LSP.

Comment: A stronger argument is that since (char[]) null == (Object) null, any function (like String.valueOf) should intuitively give the same result. Of course that cannot be guaranteed with overloading, so quite some respectable language designers argue that overloading is a feature a language should not have.
Because of this, I'd argue a different specification for either `String.valueOf` overload, preventing this, would arguably have been better (you haven't defended the current spec). Of course there's no way to change the behavior now, so reporting it as a bug would have little effect.

Answer (score 16):

There are lots of overloaded `String.valueOf` methods in Java. Further, in Java `null` has any and all types so that anything (that isn't a primitive) can be `null`.

So, when you call `(String.valueOf((Object)null)` you call the `valueOf` method that takes an `Object` as use explicitly cast `null` to `Object`.

In the second example you don't explicitly cast the `null` to any particular type so in fact you call the `valueOf` method with a `char[]` which throws an NPE.

From the [JLS §15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)

> The second step searches the type determined in the previous step for
>   member methods. This step uses the name of the method and the types of
>   the argument expressions to locate methods that are both accessible
>   and applicable, that is, declarations that can be correctly invoked on
>   the given arguments.
>
> There may be more than one such method, in which case the most
>   specific one is chosen. The descriptor (signature plus return type) of
>   the most specific method is one used at run time to perform the method
>   dispatch.

In this case `char[]` is *more specific* than `Object` so it is called when no explicit cast of `null` is made.

Comment: And hence the bottom line is avoid passing raw `null` as arguments to methods rather cast them to param type of that method. :)

Answer (score 6):

Although I accepted already an answer I would like to add the exact answer to the question, because the two answers concentrate on explaining the trap I walked into.

The difference between `(Object)null` and `null` is that the type of the first is forced to `Object` but the type of the second is not, as one could think, forced to `Object`. Instead it could also be an array instead of an object.

So the conclusion is: pass `(Object)null` instead of `null` as an argument to a method to be sure to get exactly the method working on objects instead of any other method working on arrays.

Comment: Well yes, as Rohit already mentioned, a method call will always be matched to the method with the most specific subtype.