# String.valueOf() Null pointer

Tags: java

In java Doc it is written that String.valueOf() will return "null" if argument is null, but in practical it gives null pointer exception for null argument. I want to understand the reason. Tried looking on GREPCODE, could not get it. Please explain

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131865/why-does-string-valueofnull-throw-a-nullpointerexception

Comment: Did you read docs carefully? It says: "Unless otherwise noted, passing a null argument to a constructor or method in this class will cause a NullPointerException to be thrown."

Answer (score 1):

If you have code like this:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf((Object) null));
```

"null" is printed to the console. If you have:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(null));
```

a NPE is thrown.

That is because valueOf is overloaded.

[String.valueOf(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

[String.valueOf(char[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%5b%5d%29)

To explain the NPE, if you examine the code for String.valueOf(char[]):

```
return new String(data);
```

and the constructor for String is:

```
public String(char value[]) {
    this.value = Arrays.copyOf(value, value.length);
}
```

On this line, a NPE is thrown with the statement value.length.

Answer (score 0):

Your call activates `String.valueOf(char value[])` that throws NPE in case of null argument. `String.valueOf(Object value)` works only if you drop the object to this method. Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3131884/1051509)