# java NullPointerException error converting int to string

Tags: java

I have an HTML form that calls a Java servlet and the form contains 20 checkboxes (e.g. with names of `c1`, `c2`, `c3`...`c20`).

I'm trying to capture the value of those checkboxes in a java boolean array `cbox`.

The following code...

```
int ii=0;
boolean cbox[] = new boolean[20];
for (ii=0; ii<20; ii++)
   cbox[ii] = (req.getParameter("c"+String.valueOf((int)(ii+1))).equals("on"))?true:false;
```

gives a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

But, I don't get a run time error if I were to change it to (e.g. remove `ii` in `valueOf`):

```
   cbox[ii] = (req.getParameter("c"+String.valueOf((int)(1))).equals("on"))?true:false;
```

Of course, that doesn't get me where I want. I must be making a silly mistake somewhere but I can't spot it. Does anyone see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in servlet, you will receive `on` as default value for html selected checkbox else null. Since all checkboxes are not checked you get NPE. Try this code snippet:

```
boolean[] cbox = new boolean[20];
for(int i = 0; cbox.length > i; i++) {
   cbox[i] = null != req.getParameter("c" + (1 + i));//if not null then true else false
}
```

You can also go with other option:

in your *html/jsp* create checkboxes with same name but different value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="2"/>
...
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="20"/>
```

in *servlet* you can fetch all checked boxes with single line:

```
String[] cbox = req.getParameterValues("cbox");
```

Here you won't get `on` as value, its gona be `1`, `2` and so on as per selection. Only checked boxes you will get here.

Comment: Thanks @arvind, at least I verified your first solution above works great. Very concise!

Answer (score 2):

A [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) occur when you try to reference an Object that is not initialized (null).

Looking at your code, there are two possibilities :

- req is null `req.getParameter`.
- The parameter you are trying to retrieve does not exists hence is null `req.getParameter("c"+String.valueOf((int)(ii+1)))`.

By the way, if your returned parameter is already a boolean, there is no need to check the value of it and return true or false as it value is already true or false. You can simplify it to :

```
cbox[ii] = (req.getParameter("c"+String.valueOf((int)(ii+1))).equals("on"));
```

---

**Edit :** To answer to your comment, you could validate if the parameter exist easily :

```
String param = req.getParameter("c" + String.valueOf(ii + 1));
cbox[ii] = "on".equals(param);
```

To be even more secure, I would also check `req` to make sure it is not null.

```
if(req != null)
{
    String param = req.getParameter("c" + String.valueOf((ii + 1));
    cbox[ii] = "on".equals(param);
}
```

Notice that I removed the cast `(int)ii + 1` as the expression is already of type integer.

Also, if `ii` is only to be used as an iterator id, you can declare it directly in the loop, so instead of doing this :

```
int ii = 0;
for(ii = 0; ii < 20; ii++)
```

You can directly write `for(int ii = 0; ii < 20; ii++)`

Comment: That might explain it... when the checkbox is not selected, it's value is null.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still giving same error. I think it's because `String.valueOf(null)` gives NullPointerException (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131865/why-does-string-valueofnull-throw-a-nullpointerexception ).

Comment: @user46688 `ii + 1` can't be null. My validation was actually wrong, see new edit.

Comment: Yes, your edit is now working fine. Note there's a typo though with an extra  left parenthesis `((ii+1))` should be `(ii+1))`. Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome :). Please also check new edit, as I've given an even more secure validation.

Comment: plus 1 for the "on".equals(param)

Comment: Hmm, the simplification is yielding NPE. But, the previous code worked: `Object param = req.getParameter("c" + String.valueOf(ii + 1));
          cbox[ii] = param != null ? ((String)param).equals("on") : false;`

Comment: @user46688 I know the previous one also worked, however I would still recommend to use this one.