# Why does System.out.print on null object work?

Tags: java

Let's consider following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = null;
    Object o = null;

    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(o);

    System.out.println(i.toString());
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

That's quite obvious that last two prints will cause `NullPointerException`. One can't call method on null object. 
The question is why first two prints work? Aren't they calling `toString()` as well?

Comment: Did you try to step into `println` using a debugger?

Comment: Further reading, along with the answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131865/why-does-string-valueofnull-throw-a-nullpointerexception

Comment: @LutzHorn, that requires the source code of JDK, and to tell the debugger where to look for it, not so trivial, and certainly not common

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. That's interesting.

Comment: Nit about the title: *objects* are never `null`; only *references* can be `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they aren't.

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` and it calls `String.valueOf(x)` on the argument (as described in the the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object))).

Comment: I've added a link to the relevant Javadoc, feel free to roll back if you don't want this.

Comment: I've closed as dup to the relevant existing question. And still wondering why nobody else had that idea ...

Comment: Sometimes it's more fun to answer trivial questions than try to find duplicates.

Comment: @Kayaman I know, and its not like that I never did that ... probably I am just envious that Jarred "I will downvote any question and any answer that even shows the slightest close distance to some DUP" wasn't around. As he seems to always be around when I do *accidentally* answer DUPs.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not.

There is a null pointer check inside of `System.out.println` (*).

Something along the lines of

```
println(x == null ? "null" : x.toString());
```

(*) the argument goes through [`String#valueOf`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29), which takes care of this.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: And why not flag as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the implementation of `print(String s)`:

```
public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
}
```

If the object happens to be `null`, it simply writes `"null"`. Taken from [java.io.PrintStream:GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Haha, there's even two null-checks actually performed for the OP's call - first, `PrintStream.println()` does the check mentioned in my answer, then calls `PrinsStream.print()` which checks for null again as per yours.

Comment: This code path isn't called in OP's code: `s` is `"null"`, not `null`, because `String.valueOf(s)` is never null.

Comment: @AndyTurner ah that's right. I stepped to the lowest point in the calling hierarchy where the null check is done and overlooked the `String.valueOf(s)` before.