# Andriod Studio Movie Searching app stops working after login button clicked. Link to github also shared

Tags: java, android, api, server, android-volley

[Link to github Repository](https://github.com/bchhen/AndroidStudioMovieApp)

**Application uses Volley library to make HTTP requests to servers**

secondly
what does this below variable means?

String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3979/api/idm/login";

**Log Cat**
[image: Log Cat]

Answer (score 1):

Your server is not returning statusCode. If you pass your value as an Int into "valueOf" function it will cause nullpointerexception. To prevent this you need pass your variable as an Object.

For more information:
[Why does String.valueOf(null) throw a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131865/why-does-string-valueofnull-throw-a-nullpointerexception)