# Why is the output like this?

Tags: java, polymorphism, scjp

```
class Another {
    public void method(Object o) {
        System.out.println("This is in method which takes object");
    }
    public void method(String s) {
        System.out.println("This is method which takes string");
    }
}

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Another an = new Another();
        an.method(null);
    }
}
```

When I try to execute this, I get

> This is method which takes string

as the output. Why not "This is in method which takes object"? Object can also be null and string can also be null, why doesn't it invoke first method?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5), in such cases of overloaded methods where both methods can handle the provided arguments, the method with more specific argument is chosen. Since `String` is more specific than `Object` (`String` extends `Object`), `void method(String)` is chosen and called.

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly as specified in JLS:

> #### [JLS 15.12.2.5  Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5)
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the *most specific* method is chosen.

A `String` is-a `Object`, but not all `Object` is-a `String`. Therefore, `String` is *more specific* than `Object`, hence why the `String` overload is chosen in the above example.

---

It is worth noting that *this exact question* (in essence) appeared in the wonderful [*Java Puzzlers*](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) (highly recommended), specifically *Puzzle 46: The Case of the Confusing Constructor*

> Java's overload resolution process operates in two phases. The first phase selects all the methods or constructors that are accessible and applicable. The second phase selects the *most specific* of the methods or constructors selected in the first phase. One method or constructor is less specific than another if it can accept any parameters passed to the other
>
> The key to understanding this puzzle is that **the test for which method or constructor is most specific does not use the *actual parameters***: the parameters appearing in the invocation. They are used only to determine which overloadings are applicable. Once the compiler determines which overloadings are applicable and accessible, it selects the most specific overloading, using only the *formal parameters*: the parameters appearing in the declaration.

---

I will close with a quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, **Item 41: Use overloading judiciously**:

> The rules that determine which overloading is selected are extremely complex. They take up *thirty-three* pages in the language specification, and few programmers understand all of their subtleties.

Needless to say, this book is also *highly recommended*.

#### See also

- [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading)
- [Method Overloading. Can you overuse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248222/method-overloading-can-you-overuse-it)

---

#### On explicit casting

> So how can I invoke the `Object` overload with `null` argument?

Simple: cast the `null` to type `Object`. There are several scenarios where this is useful/necessary, and this is one of them.

> What if I have an overload that takes, say, an `Integer`?

Then the method invocation is *ambiguous*, and compile-time error occurs.

> #### [JLS 15.12.2.5  Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5)
>
> It is possible that no method is the most specific, because there are two or more methods that are maximally specific. In this case [... with some exceptions] we say that the method invocation is *ambiguous*, and a compile-time error occurs.

To resolve the ambiguity, again you can cast the `null` (or other expression) to the desired overload type.

#### See also

- [JLS 15.12.2.10 Example: Overloading Ambiguity](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.10)

Comment: Now, what if you have another method that takes a Date?  Since neither String is-a Date nor Date is-a String, is the behavior unspecified?  Is it an error?

Comment: @Justin: yes, it's ambiguous and therefore a compile-time error. JLS fully specifies this, and has illustrative examples.

Comment: incidentally, this is the one question that I always ask in Java interviews :)

Answer (score 5):

The compiler will always find the narrowest match possible when resolving overloaded method calls.

Btw the Java convention is to use uppercase names for classes, i.e. `Another`.

Comment: yep, the compiler doesn't care that you happen to be passing null, it will find the narrowest match regardless of the value of the parameter.

if you wanted your method that takes an object to be called, you would need to cast explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that with Java 6 (I think Java 5 would have thrown a compiler error) in a case like this, it will select tho lowest level class to attribute the null to. (since String is an Object it is lower in the hierarchy)